# Real time Multiplayer or Turn based multiplayer API?

Tags: android, google-play-services, multiplayer, google-play-games

I am new to multi-player game development. I am basically making a board game for Android which requires to have a time limit for taking a turn, kind of like Online Multiplayer Chess which has a turn timer for both players. A timer runs when a player has to make a move and continues from where it left of when the same player needs to make a move. Similar timer is maintained for the second player.

I am not exactly getting which API should I use for this purpose. Real time Multiplayer or Turn based multi-player API? Any suggestions?

Update:
I have finally used the Real Time Multiplayer(RTM) API as it provides almost everything. Basically it makes a room that checks for player drop-out unlike Turn Based API which is asynchronous and there is no direct way to check player drop-out in it. Plus RTM provides Real time sharing which I require due to my game complexity(I needed a way in which I can show every move that the other player makes before making a final move which will act as a turn changer).

Now the thing that was not provided was the turn mechanism which I implemented myself in the Real Time API. I have modified the Button Clicker and the results are as follows:

The other player is chosen as the first player

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbBvt.png]

Once the other player clicks on the button, the turn changes and also score updates to 1.
(Score is modified to a no. that is common for both. So if I click on the button it will turn to 2.)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jwt0R.png]

Comment: nikhil did you successfully made any multiplayer game ?
because now i am stuck and couldn't understand any thing at : https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/turnbasedMultiplayer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is built-in to [Google Play Game Services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/turnbasedMultiplayer).

Specifically the gms package [com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.turnbased](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/package-summary.html).

You really don't need a timer to be built into the API because it is in the Android Core [CountDownTimer class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

What you would do is you would set up the CountDownTimer and then for the `onFinish()` method, you would say to switch players turn.

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
     }
  }.start();
```

Comment: The timer is also built in?

Comment: Thank you for replying. But my point is what will happen in case of a crash or a phone call? The timer will be dismissed as it is maintained locally. Is there a work around so that one can continue  the game in case he/she comes back before the timer expires?

Comment: @Nikhil That is going a little more towards game design rather than a proper API I feel like. You may want to pay a visit to [Android StackExchange](http://android.stackexchange.com/) or [Game Development StackExchange](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/). I am not an Android developer by any means but I am assuming you're going to have a database to store user information so you may want to keep track of the time server-side.

Comment: When you receive a phonecall, the application doesn't exit -- it simply runs in the background so you can still have your timer running locally. If your phone actually crashes though, I believe you will need to depend on the server for the time. Like I said though, this really depends how you design the game -- if someone's phone crashes, do you really want the other player to wait for this guy? You might just want that to be a surrender. Here is information on [how to save data to a SQL database](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html).